# Point an array of pointers to an array of arrays

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, 2d

I am trying to point to an array of arrays (learning purposes). I use this line for that purpose:

```
int Arr[6][6];    
int (*ptr)[6][6];
ptr = &Arr;
```

Is this correct?
(EDIT: I intend to use a pointer to a 6x6 array. Also, considering I wish to take input and print it out also, which kind of declaration is better? array of pointers or pointer to 6x6 array?)

Next,

(The "reading and printing of 2d array using pointer" code is a total mess, which is why I won't show it here.)

I want to use scanf and printf to take input through ptr (which should assign it to Arr), and then print both Arr and ptr to see the syntax (and if it works at all). Obviously both printed arrays should be the same.

What syntax should I use? It's extremely confusing and I hope this will help me learn better.

## Reading and printing through pointer:

```
for (i = 0; i < 6; i++)

{
    printf_s("\nEnter values for row %d (Enter 0 for 1-1, 2-2 etc.:\n", i + 1);
    for (j = 0; j < 6; j++)
    {
        printf_s("Row %d Column %d", i + 1, j + 1);
        scanf_s("%d", &(*ptr)[i][j]); ........(ptr)[i][j] doesn't allocate to Arr correctly
    }
}
for (i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    {
        printf_s("\n");
        for (j = 0; j < 6; j++)
        {
            printf_s("%d\t", (*ptr)[i][j]); .........*(ptr)[i][j] is wrong because it dereferences the whole 2D array.
        }
    }
```

Credits: haccks
(I changed the question a lot of times, so I'm pointing out mistakes I did during the same)

Comment: Why are we not allowed to see the declaration of `Arr`? Licensing issues?

Comment: No...Arr is just an int array. I can either define it here, or take input for it. In any case, my question is only about the behaviour of ptr, so I excluded Arr to make the question simpler. Wonder if I should put up the whole mess I made? :D

Comment: array of pointers: `T *arr[size];`; array of pointers to array-of-arrays: `T (*arr[size])[width][length]`.

Comment: @user3138129; No..`Arr` is not just an `int` array. It is a 2D array of `int`s.

Comment: I intended to use an integer pointer to a 6x6 array, which is why (*ptr)[6][6]. Is this right? Also, I don't understand what you just said. Sorry, I'm a beginner.

Comment: Also, pointer to array of pointers to array-of-arrays: `int (*(*arr)[size])[length][width];` - this is what you are looking for.

Comment: @H2CO3; Please don't do that. He will be confused for sure.

Comment: @hackks, right, Arr is a 2D array of ints. And I am confused too.

Comment: @user3138129; Read my answer.

Comment: @haccks Yup. But that's what he asked for so... :P

Comment: @H2CO3; That was typo (I know you knew that) :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`int (*ptr)[6][6];` declare `ptr` as a pointer to an array of `6` elements , each of which are array of `6` integers ( of type `int (*)[6][6]` ) . Now `&Arr` is also `int (*)[6][6]` type, your assignment is legal.
In your `scanf_s` argument, you are missing `&`. This should be

```
scanf_s("%d", &(*ptr)[i][j]);
```

Note that `(*ptr)[i][j]` is of `int` type. It is like `Arr[i][j]`. To store values to `Arr[i][j]` you need `&`, similarly `&` is used here to store values `(*ptr)[i][j]`.

See the corrected program :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    int Arr[6][6];
    int (*ptr)[6][6];
    ptr = &Arr;

    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    {
        printf("\nEnter values for row %d (Enter 0 for 1-1, 2-2 etc.:\n", i + 1);
        for (int j = 0; j < 6; j++)
        {
            printf("Row %d Column %d: ", i + 1, j + 1);
            scanf("%d", &(*ptr)[i][j]);

        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 6; j++)
            printf("%d\t", (*ptr)[i][j]);
        printf("\n");
    }

}
```

**Output:** http://ideone.com/q6BQ61

Comment: Technically, if `Arr` is also an array of arrays of arrays of integers, e.g. `int Arr[X][6][6]`, that would be a legal assignment as well.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg; In that case I think `Arr` would be the legal assignment.

Comment: And how do I take input to ptr?

Comment: You can do this by `(*ptr)[i][j]`.

Comment: okay, I'll show what I tried in another edit in the question. It didn't work though..

Comment: Okay that worked, now should I just try dereferencing to print it out? I'll try that!

Comment: No. You do not need to dereference that. You can print simply by `printf("%d", (*ptr)[i][j]);`.

Comment: Okay...I tried this...Reading and printing the array through pointer is correct, but the array Arr prints wrongly (First row becomes 1st column, and all other values become zero.).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44459/discussion-between-user3138129-and-haccks)